# Any way to bypass windows domain account?

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, windowsdomainaccount

I am installing Dynamics AX 2012 (single pc installation) on my laptop and it gives me alert that

> You are logged on with a local computer account 'PC-NAME'. You must be
>   logged on with a domain account to run Microsoft Dynamics AX Setup

Not familiar with windows domain accounts and networking, just wishing to get a solution on how to bypass this, any 'single pc' solution for domain account? I mean is there any windows service that can solve this?

Comment: You need Enterprise Resource Planning - and your entire organisation is running on a single PC?

Comment: thats for development purpose, and dynamics do provide single pc development environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Dynamics requires a domain, so, no. You might want to consider creating a virtual machine on your laptop and running a domain controller on it and installing Dynamics there.

Comment: VM solutions looks feasible, on domain controller part, what utilities would be required in windows 7?

Comment: You'd need to install Windows Server 2008 R2 in the VM to make it a domain controller.